# Azure Logic App - Row limit in outputs (shows first 500 rows)

Tags: azure, output, rows, limit, azure-logic-apps

I have a problem showing the results in Outputs.
In Outputs is shows only the first 500 rows of results.

[image: prtsc of result]

my expected result is over 600,000 rows.

has anyone had a problem with this, is there a solution?

Comment: try adding screenshot of the flow of your logic app

Comment: Please before you ask a question, review this section: [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is that you can turn on pagination for that particular connector and set the threshold.

[image]

**REFERENCES:**
[Get more items or records with pagination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exceed-default-page-size-with-pagination#turn-on-pagination)

Comment: I don't have a Pagination option in settings on the connector. I use "Run a query against a dataset connector"

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Pagination option in settings on the connector.
I use "Run a query against a dataset connector"
[settings of connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhWXv.jpg)